# Oracle Apex column link from LOV values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, lov

Can you please advise if below is even possible. Using Oracle 11g and APEX 4.2.6.

I have a data grid that brings all tasks from a master table. But show the task name via a LOV.

I am trying to add links, via Column links. But I must turn off the LOV to make this work.  Which would give me link. But this is not very helpful.

**Example below.**

```
<a href="f?p=103:5:7907259112753::NO::P5_MAST_ID:44193">44193</a>
```

Is there a way, so I can still use a LOV. So that the return value gives me the ID for the link, but the Display value gives me the anchor text.

**Example below.**

```
<a href="f?p=103:5:7907259112753::NO::P5_MAST_ID: 44193">Weekend</a>
```

Many thanks

Comment: Do you want to have a LOV, where you will choose value, and after that your link will change accordingly to return value?

Comment: Each column is set as display as Text (based on LOV) (not dropdown)

for example.
From database
Col1 col2 col3
44193|41123|44193

With LOV
Col1 col2 col3
Weekend|MOD| Weekend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm mostly used to Apex 4.1, but this approach should work.

You don't need an LOV. Your report query should include both the `MAST_ID` and the `TASK_NAME` columns. Hide the `TASK_NAME` column and set `MAST_ID` as the linking column. If you set the *Link Text* (under *Column Link*) to `#TASK_NAME#`, you should get the desired result. *Display As* should be left at the default (`Display as Text` etc).

Answer (score 0):

They added a new feature now where you can add a link to your item under: "Link" attribute.